# How can do a dynamic query in this scenario . sql 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, dynamic-sql

I am trying to enter userids from the query to send them emails .
it does not work and gives me this error

> Msg 14624, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 238 At
>   least one of the following parameters must be specified. "@recipients,
>   @copy_recipients, @blind_copy_recipients".

```
declare @bodymsg nvarchar(max)
select @bodymsg = '<font face="calibiri" size="4" >Dear Users</font><br><br>
<font face="calibiri" size="5" color="red">Please Explain the Exrta Locked Faxes</font><br><br>
<font face="calibiri" size="4" >Check the Last Hour Snapshot Details Attached.<br><br>
Thanks</font></end>'

declare @users_fetched  varchar(max)
set @users_fetched = 'SELECT distinct Locked_Faxes_Last_Hour_Snap.userid from Locked_Faxes_Last_Hour_Snap'


declare @recipients varchar(max)

SELECT 
@recipients = STUFF((SELECT ';' + concerned_staff.staff_email from concerned_staff where (concerned_staff.staff_id in ('@users_fetched')) 
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                       ), 1, 1, '')

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail


@recipients = @recipients ,

@body= @bodymsg ,
@subject = 'Alert !!! Locked Faxes Violation Last Hour Snaps' ,
@profile_name = 'Database Profile 1',
@query = 'use qtel select * from dbo.Locked_Faxes_Last_Hour_Snap' ,
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename ='Locked_Faxes_Last_Hour_Snap.csv',
@query_result_separator =',',
@query_result_no_padding=1,
@exclude_query_output=1,
@append_query_error=0,
@query_result_header =1,
@body_format ='HTML',
@importance= 'HIGH';
```

Comment: If you comment out the exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail command and do select @recipients what does it return?

Comment: @scsimon when i select that atrecipients it gives out "null" , and when i select atusers_fetched it gives out "SELECT distinct Locked_Faxes_Last_Hour_Snap.userid from Locked_Faxes_Last_Hour_Snap" :(

Comment: Why do you even use dynamic sql? You don't need it. Just put your select in subquery instead of `'@users_fetched'` and run it. RIght now you are mixing query string where it does not belong, dynamic query would need a whole different approach.

Comment: Thanks @NenadZivkovic who can put the sub query you mean to replace my query from the variable in the master query ?

Comment: did you try putting a `;` on the line before the EXEC?  Also take out the double blank line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need dynamic sql here. Just put your query for fetching users as a where condition IN sub-query, when you create recipients:

```
SELECT 
@recipients = STUFF((SELECT ';' + concerned_staff.staff_email 
                     from concerned_staff 
                     where concerned_staff.staff_id in 
                     (
                         SELECT Locked_Faxes_Last_Hour_Snap.userid 
                         from Locked_Faxes_Last_Hour_Snap
                     )
                     FOR XML PATH('')
                     ), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: THANKS A TON WORKED LIKE A CHARM :) Lovely